# Cocoa / OS X: Determine whether the currently selected keyboard has a numeric keypad

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How do you determine the PHYSICAL type / layout of a keyboard attached to a Mac? I'm trying to determine whether the currently selected keyboard has a numeric keypad, but can't see an obvious kTISPropertyXXXXXXX to identify the number of keys / layout, a bit of example code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        TISInputSourceRef currentKeyLayoutRef;
        currentKeyLayoutRef = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource();

        NSLog(@"Basic Info: keyboard_type=%u, layoutName=%@, localizedName=%@, languages: %@\n",
              LMGetKbdType(),
              TISGetInputSourceProperty(currentKeyLayoutRef, kTISPropertyInputSourceID),
              TISGetInputSourceProperty(currentKeyLayoutRef, kTISPropertyLocalizedName),
              TISGetInputSourceProperty(currentKeyLayoutRef, kTISPropertyInputSourceLanguages)
              );
//        NSLog(@"List: %@", TISGetInputSourceProperty(currentKeyLayoutRef, kTISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Wondering how Apple have coded the Keyboard Viewer app, as it shows an extended keyboard when a USB / Bluetooth keyboard is attached, are they simply looking for a non internal keyboard in the USB device list e.g.  
     ioreg -Src IOUSBDevice | grep "USB Product Name" | grep "Keyboard" | egrep -v "Hub|Internal"